# Learning Logic and Metric Spaces

Tags: soft-question, education

I want to learn how to manipulate metric spaces. I have been reading this book about metric spaces.

[http://www.amazon.com/Metric-Spaces-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1846283698/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1424394655&sr=8-1&keywords=metric+spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1846283698)

However, the author notes that the reader needs a good understanding of abstract logic. The author gives a quick review of abstract logic and set theory which I have read several times. I have no prior experience in mathematical abstract logic

However, when I delve into Chapter 1, I have a hard time understanding the proofs. Should I continue trying to work at the proofs or perhaps I am too much of a beginner and should read a "prerequisite book" so to speak.